# External hard drive won't format due to "read-only" files

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, file-format, read-only

I have an external hard drive that has all of my media and files on it. It normally boots right up, but for some reason it's been having trouble.

I normally use it on 2 computers, one with windows vista and the other with windows 7 (that is in much better condition).

When I plug it into the USB drive it now states that I "need to format disc drive F before I can use it"

I try to format the drive and it almost finishes until it taps out and says that it can't open the drive. It asks if it's plugged in correctly (which it is) or is a read-only file, and suggests that I look for how to change read-only files.

How can I go about fixing this without wiping everything clean? I'm completely fine with deleting the "read-only" file that's screwing everything up, I just don't want to lose the other 10 years of my life.

any help would be immensely appreciated!!

Comment: Is the drive externally powered or USB powered type?   
How does it show up in the Windows Disk managment?   What do the SMART tests show? I would not be letting the system format it at this time :-)

Comment: Although your question title says to format the drive before you can use it, formatting it will wipe the disk. You will lose the other 10yrs of your life! The disk is showing it needs formatting because of a partition table problem or the disk is failing. If you need the files on the disk **do not format it**! Formatting the disk will tell Windows that the disk is blank and it can write to it wherever it pleases - **overwriting your important files**. Do you have a backup of your files?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using `diskpart`.

Run these commands in an elevated (Administrator) command prompt, hitting enter at the line breaks:

```
diskpart

list disk

select disk n (n being your drive to format; make sure it's the correct capacity to ensure you've identified the right one)

attributes disk clear readonly

clean

create partition primary

format fs=ntfs

exit
```

Should get you going.  Next thing to try would be [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php); throw it in your machine, boot to it with the USB drive connected, and format that sucker.  I've never had that not work.

Comment: Why do you need to use GPart when you can simply use the command prompt UEFI provides? Exactly what can be done by GPart that can't be done by UEFI cmd?

Comment: @Pacerier, I don't have much experience with the UEFI command line, so I explained the methodology I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done with multiple options, if you have a linux OS nearby, connect your Ext HDD with it, and remove the read only attribute. If this doesn't help.

Open Windows in Safe Mode with Command Prompt.

Here only those services will run, which are required to start CMD and display.

Connect you HDD with computer.

If the HDD is assigned drive letter G:/

Type G:/ and Hit Enter (You will enter into drive G)

Type DIR (HIT Enter) - This will show the list of directories in HDD.

Now Run the Command

attrib -r -s -h /s /d

the above command will take a while to execute, depending on the number of files and directories

Now try to format the drive in any way, command or GUI

Hope this helps if you fail doing it the other way