# Seagate external hard disk cannot format and can not show in computer

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, formatting

I formatted my seagate external hard disk with NTFS using Ubuntu Disk Utility. After that it is bricked, and now I cannot see it as a hard disk in mac /ubuntu /windows, the device can be detected by computer.

Disk Details:
 - Brand: seagate expansion portable drive
 - Model: SRD00F1
 - Serial: NA42Q8HM 
 - Size: 1TB

Problems:

- when I set internal hard drive as first boot, the usb external drive, when plugged in, will make the computer failed to boot from internal hard drive.
- diskpart and disk management can only work when they are open first and then plug in the usb hard drive, otherwise they will stuck. (see pics below)
- sometimes when I plug in, the disk change to readonly and I follow [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/789441/external-hard-drive-wont-format-due-to-read-only-files), I didn't work for me.

I tried many times and also failed many times. 
What should I do? Is there anyway to reset hard drive?

[Related Images](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz1-hopez9CGaUF2V0FjVlNFdWM&usp=sharing) (sorry I don't have rights to post images)

- [BIOS recognize usb hard disk]
- [Disk management can see hard disk but stuck]
- [Disk change to readonly]
- [Diskpart can see the disk]
- [Device Manager detect usb hard disk]
- [diskpart list volume not work]
- [change readonly fail]

Answer (score 0):

You can write zeros to the drive. This will erase all the data that is on the HDD and will reset it to factory defaults. Look for a software with a DOS version to avoid using Windows.

Comment: DOS can not recognize my external usb hard drive, any tools suggested to do zero fill in my usb external hard drive. Tks.

Comment: You can have a look at Hiren's BootCD it has some useful HDD tools.

Comment: My favorite is Western Digitals "Data Lifeguard" tools, I use it in windows for zero fill.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD I have tried Hiren's BootCD. The Dos tool inside can not recognize hdd.